# Getting error: Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type" when importing .CSV in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, csv, import, cron

I am trying to create a new website for my client and they have a bit of a funky system in place. Essentially they use a service that imports tens of thousands of products onto the site every day with their price rules etc. For the most part this is good however the data isn't of the greatest quality so for their bestsellers they have an automated product import to overwrite a few hundred products with some higher quality images, descriptions and so on.

So, here is the problem.

I am trying to move the product import over to the development site and make sure it is all working well. I have copied all the files across and checked that they are all using the correct  URLs, category IDs etc. I then set up the same Import profile in Magento and try running the profile in a pop-up, then, this is what happens:

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

And here is an image of the errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXpm4.png

And this is the action XML code:

```
    <action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[2_MANUAL_FEED_DAILY_IMPORT.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="root_catalog_id"><![CDATA[2]]></var>
    <var name="reimport_images"><![CDATA[false]]></var>
    <var name="reimport_description"><![CDATA[false]]></var>
    <var name="deleteall_andreimport_images"><![CDATA[false]]></var>
    <var name="exclude_images"><![CDATA[false]]></var>
    <var name="exclude_gallery_images"><![CDATA[false]]></var>
    <var name="map">
        <map name="gallery"><![CDATA[gallery]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="append_tier_prices"><![CDATA[true]]></var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_productimport</var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

And here is the all import(ant) sample from the .CSV file which is saved as comma separated and UTF8:

```
    sku,store,is_in_stock,category_ids,manufacturer,weight,qty,price
SRP-LE-24,Main Website Store,1,Video Conferencing,Smart,1,35,699.99
SRP-LE-32,Main Website Store,1,Video Conferencing,Smart,1,35,789.99
SRP-LE-RCV-1,Main Website Store,1,Video Conferencing,Smart,1,0,399.99
SRP-LE-RMT-1,Main Website Store,1,Video Conferencing,Smart,1,0,84.99
SRP-PE-24,Main Website Store,1,Video Conferencing,Smart,1,35,739.99
```

URL to site: http://bit.ly/1mAxK2a

Also, the site is running on Magento 1.8.1.0

I'm afraid I don't have too much experience in Magento so i'm not sure if this is formatted right or if the problem is really obvious but if anybody can see what's going on here I appreciate all the help. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create new products via the import dataflow. But as I know, the import is working only to update the products when you define only a few fields.
Instead, try to use all the magento fields (even if you leave blank where you don't have information) will create those products in the store.